# Displaying XML feed contents

Tags: php, simplexml

Using simpleXML, how do you display the contents of a feed. I mean actually display the XML on a page so that I can see the schema?

Comment: see how to parse xml (simplexml, DOM)

Comment: `echo $simpleXMLElement->asXML();`, in an HTML context (you could set text/plain headers of course...), you'd have to add `<pre>` tags or use `htmlspecialchars()` to actually see it.

Comment: Thanks so much Wrikken, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my example i will use XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
    <name>Menus</name>
    <folder>menus</folder>
    <install>install.php</install>
</module>
```

You can use to load xml file in a variable:

```
$mod = simplexml_load_file($XMLfile);
```

and call fields:

```
echo $mod->module->name;
echo $mod->module->folder;
echo $mod->module->install;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("URL GOES HERE");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```

Will print a readable array of the object.

And a VALID RSS feed has this schema:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $items){
  $title = $items->title;
  $link = $items->link;
  $description = $items->description;
  $pubDate = strtotime($items->pubDate);
  $pubDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $pubDate);
}
```

Along with a few other attributes.